# Error updating tzdata 2018f (Released 2018-10-18) with tzupdater-2.2.0

Tags: java, timezone

I'm trying to update JVM's Time Zone info using [TZUpdater 2.2.0](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/tzupdater-download-513681.html).

```
> [root@local tzupdater-2.2.0]# java -jar tzupdater.jar -V
  tzupdater version 2.2.0-b01
  JRE tzdata version: tzdata2018d
  tzupdater tool would update with tzdata version: tzdata2018f
```

So, I'm running the command below:

```
> [root@local tzupdater-2.2.0]# java -jar tzupdater.jar -l
```

However, I'm getting this error message:

```
Failed: java.lang.Exception: Failed while parsing file '/tmp/tz.tmp_1/asia' on line 1655 'Rule  Japan   1948    1951    -   Sep Sat>=8  25:000S'
java.lang.Exception: Failed while parsing file '/tmp/tz.tmp_1/asia' on line 1655 'Rule  Japan   1948    1951    -   Sep Sat>=8  25:00   0   S'
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.parseFile(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:377)
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.compile(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:191)
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.<init>(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:307)
    at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.ExternalModule.compileToJSRBinary(ExternalModule.java:153)
    at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.run(TimezoneUpdater.java:230)
    at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.main(TimezoneUpdater.java:634)
Caused by: tools.tzdb.DateTimeException: Invalid value for SecondOfDay value: 90000
    at tools.tzdb.ChronoField.checkValidValue(ChronoField.java:173)
    at tools.tzdb.LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(LocalTime.java:210)
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.parseMonthDayTime(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:475)
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.parseRuleLine(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:399)
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.parseFile(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:354)
    ... 5 more
```

I'm using https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzdata-latest.tar.gz as the source for the tzdata bundle.

*Edited -* In addition, I'm using either Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17) and OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-1~deb9u1-b13), meanwhile I have same reported problem using TZUpdater or [ZIUpdater](https://www.azul.com/products/open-source-tools/ziupdater-time-zone-tool)

Can anyone help me about this issue? Any comment will be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: While you don't solve this issue, you can manually change your timezone based on GMT, like defining in the Java Options `-Duser.timezone=GMT[-03:00]` (instead of `-Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo` (or none), for example). Just have in mind that when 4th November comes you must remove this change (I'm assuming you are using Brazilian timezone based on your comments on other answers), otherwise your application will be 1 hour less than it should be.

Comment: @LucasBasquerotto we are using this palliative solution. However the system that uses this solution is for high productive and affect several consumers. We need a more robust and automatic solution. In this moment, I'm using both `d` and `e` IANA reference release. But JVMs is ignoring both old versions and it using another source of time zone from SO.

Comment: In my case I used IANA `2018f` except for `asia` that is using `2018e`, because of the problem you mentioned. I too want an automated solution and only gave this comment as a fast immediate solution. In my case, IANA `2018e` and `2018f` worked for java time, but not for JodaTime (https://www.joda.org/joda-time/tz_update.html). The approach of `-Duser.timezone=GMT[-03:00]` fixed for JodaTime too. I'm looking in migrating from JodaTime to Java8 Time, and this probably will be fixed, without requiring this palliative solution.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, the rules for Japan in 1948-1951 changed in 2018f in an "interesting" way: officially, Japan's fall back occurred at 25:00 on Saturday, instead of 01:00 on the Sunday. That confused the Java time zone updater, as well as my own Noda Time project.

There's now a [commit to avoid 25:00 in the "rearguard" format](https://github.com/eggert/tz/commit/401c42d991d4277cd606933fc9f5d9a13d1ac228) - the rearguard format is basically more conservative, avoiding things like Ireland's negative DST.

I would expect a 2018g release at some point reasonably soon, to include that fix. Assuming the tzupdater tool uses the rearguard appropriately, I'd expect that to sort things out. If you can possibly wait until then, I'd do so. Otherwise, use the `-l` flag on tzupdater to specify a different data source, e.g. for 2018e: https://data.iana.org/time-zones/releases/tzdata2018e.tar.gz

Comment: Jon Skeet do you know if is there a possibility to use a alternative file to update tz  ? Because I'm using Brazilian tz and we need only update using partial changes used in south america brt

Comment: @EAA: See Cristian's answer - I'd just got as far as working out the `-l` option :) Just avoid 2018f but make sure you have something recent enough, and it should be fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm still seeing a problem with the 2019 bundle. Do you know if this was ever fixed? (see my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56908541/update-to-tzdata2019b-is-failing-tzupdater-version-2-2-0-b01)

Comment: @iank: You still need to use the rear-guard format at the moment, I believe.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to use version 2018f but not the Asia timezone you can use it from 2018e and the other files from 2018f.

I've created the file [tzdata2018f-01.tar.gz](https://github.com/lucasbasquerotto/my-projects/raw/master/tz/tzdata2018f-01.tar.gz) in my repository https://github.com/lucasbasquerotto/my-projects/tree/master/tz for anyone that wants to avoid making these manual changes.

There is an example of using [ziupdater](https://www.azul.com/products/open-source-tools/ziupdater-time-zone-tool/) when creating a docker image with OpenJDK, but if you use Oracle JDK you should be able to use almost the same code to use tzupdater changing

```
java -jar /app/tmp/ziupdater-1.0.1.2.jar -l file:///app/tmp/tzdata2018f-01.tar.gz
```

to

```
java -jar /app/tmp/tzupdater.jar -l file:///app/tmp/tzdata2018f-01.tar.gz
```

or even

```
java -jar tzupdater.jar -l https://github.com/lucasbasquerotto/my-projects/raw/master/tz/tzdata2018f-01.tar.gz
```

if you don't want to download it manually.

In the example in my repository it generates a Docker image, but you can use it without docker, with Java installed directly in your OS.

I executed the last example above on my local machine (that uses Oracle JDK) and the timezone was corrected successfully:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    System.out.println("Date: " + new Date()); // prints correctly now
}
```

Just make sure that you aren't using some third-party library (like Joda Time) that uses timezone data hardcoded in its own jar (or generate a jar from the source with updated timezone data, like in https://www.joda.org/joda-time/tz_update.html).

Answer (score 5):

Since [tzdata2018g](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2018-October/027116.html) is already released with the fix provided in rearguard format, please use the rearguard `tzdata` bundle with -l option.

For `tzdata2018g` the command will look like this:
`java -jar tzupdater.jar -l https://web.cs.ucla.edu/~eggert/tz/release/2018g/tzdata2018g-rearguard.tar.gz`

Comment: Thanks!  This is the right answer if you need the last version of the timezone database.

Comment: update: java -jar tzupdater.jar -l https://web.cs.ucla.edu/~eggert/tz/release/2019a/tzdata2019a-rearguard.tar.gz

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue here, and the problem seems to be just on the latest version.

Using

```
java -jar tzupdater.jar -l https://data.iana.org/time-zones/releases/tzdata2018d.tar.gz
```

(if "2018d" is enough for you) should work fine.

For some reason, after that, upgrading to the latest tzdata also worked fine (with just a warning).

Comment: Yes the problem is related to latest version 2018f (Released 2018-10-18). https://www.iana.org/time-zones

Comment: @EAA: What *exact* changes do you need? https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/NEWS says what's in each release.

Comment: @e2a I've seen from your comments you just need the brt updates. Those are already fixed on version "d". Just use it as suggested and it will fix the Brazilian summer time changes.

Comment: @CristianTM yes the version "d" has been used. It fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same error, then I fixed the downloaded file from [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzdata-latest.tar.gz), using the following shell script, which replaces the troublesome line in the file by the previous version of "asia" file, as described by @lucas-basquerotto in his post [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52953152/3335350). I've tested and it works fine!

Please, download the [TZUpdater](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/tzupdater-download-513681.html)  bundle, extract the tzupdater.jar and update the variable TZUPDATER_JAR with the full file path of the downloaded jar file in order to run the script successfully.

```
#!/bin/bash

#FULL PATH TO tzupdater.jar
TZUPDATER_JAR='/home/user/tzupdater.jar'

OUTPUT_ALL=$(java -jar $TZUPDATER_JAR -l 2>&1 >/dev/null)
echo "$OUTPUT_ALL" | grep -e "Caused by: tools.tzdb.DateTimeException: Invalid value for SecondOfDay value: 90000" > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
        FIXME_FILE=$(echo "$OUTPUT_ALL" | grep -Po "(?<=java.lang.Exception: Failed while parsing file ').+(?=' on line 1655 'Rul)")
        echo "file $FIXME_FILE contains a syntax error"

        ERROR_LINE=$(sed -n '1656,1656p' $FIXME_FILE )
        echo "Line 1655 \"$ERROR_LINE\" contains an error"
        FIXED_LINE=${ERROR_LINE/Sat>=8/Sun>=9}
        FIXED_LINE=${FIXED_LINE/25:00/0:00}
        echo "Line 1655 fixed: \"$FIXED_LINE\" ( rule \"Sat>=8 25:00\" replaced by \"Sun>=9 0:00\" as it was used to be on previous version )"
        sed -i "s/$ERROR_LINE/$FIXED_LINE/" $FIXME_FILE
        TEMP_DIR_NAME=$(dirname $FIXME_FILE)
        cd $TEMP_DIR_NAME
        mkdir tzdata
        mv tzdata.tar.gz tzdata/
        cd tzdata/
        echo "untar original tzdata.tar.gz"
        tar -xf tzdata.tar.gz
        rm tzdata.tar.gz

        FIXME_FILENAME=$(basename $FIXME_FILE)
        echo "replacing original $FIXME_FILENAME file"
        rm $FIXME_FILENAME
        cp ../$FIXME_FILENAME $FIXME_FILENAME
        echo "building a new tar ball with the fixing"
        tar -czf ../tzdata-updated.tar.gz *
        echo "installing the updated tar file (requires elevation sudo)"
        sudo java -jar $TZUPDATER_JAR -l "file:///$TEMP_DIR_NAME/tzdata-updated.tar.gz"
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
        then
                echo "something went wrong!"
                exit 2
        fi
fi
echo "installation successful!"
```

Save this is script under the name **update_jdk_tzdata.sh** and grant it permission to execute: `chmod +x update_jdk_tzdata.sh` and execute it `./update_jdk_tzdata.sh` (it requires sudo in order to update JRE files)

Comment: Note that this "fixes" the issue by changing the data. The 25:00 is entirely intentional, it just isn't handled properly (or even worked around) by Java at the moment.

Comment: I've updated the script to revert only the line where the error is reported to the previous version

Answer (score -1):

If you are having problems with the Japanese version, you can use another link for Brazil. 
java -jar tzupdater.jar -l https://data.iana.org/time-zones/releases/tzdata2018e.tar.gz

Comment: The problem is that new DST will be scheduled to start 4th November and using this release (2018e) will be scheduled to 3th November. So it's not can be used for Brazilian DST.

Comment: Why would be scheduled to november 3rd if the decree to november 4th was done in December,2017? http://pcdsh01.on.br/DecHV.html

_e_ version is from 2018-05-03 23:55

Answer (score -1):

Update your version of Java 8; the tzupdater tool just works in Java 8 update 181.

Comment: It's not jvm version. It's a problem associated with iana releases.

Comment: That is not true. From the [tzupdater-readme](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/tzupdater-readme-136440.html): "The TZUpdater tool supports all currently supported versions of the Oracle JDK and JRE, on all supported platforms."

Comment: Tzupdater is used to update tzdata without updating the JRE. So updating the JRE is not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and choose the number *0 (automatic)

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

and choose the same *0.

If you already have the tzupdater only see the version of it that is already 2018

```
java -jar tzupdater.jar -V
```

Comment: Does this definitely work? I wouldn't expect it to, unless tzupdater has been updated *really, really recently* to handle a transition time of 25:00. If you've run this yourself and successfully updated the data to 2018f, it would be worth stating that explicitly in your answer, as it would be surprising.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Tzupdater is used to update tzdata *without* updating the jvm/jre.