# Error updating tzdata 2018g with tzupdater-2.2.0

Tags: java, timezone

We tried to update to the 2018g version of JVM's Time Zone info using TZUpdater 2.2.0.

We tried with the official [latest version](https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzdata-latest.tar.gz), then with the official [2018g version](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/releases/tzcode2018g.tar.gz)

Buth both failed with the message :

```
    Failed: java.lang.Exception: Failed while parsing file 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tz.tmp_14\asia' on line 1655 'Rule     Japan   1948    1951-       Sep     Sat>=8  25:00   0       S'
java.lang.Exception: Failed while parsing file 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tz.tmp_14\asia' on line 1655 'Rule     Japan   1948    1951    -Sep     Sat>=8  25:00   0       S'
        at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.parseFile(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:377)
        at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.compile(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:191)
        at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.<init>(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:307)
        at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.ExternalModule.compileToJSRBinary(ExternalMod
ule.java:153)
        at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.run(TimezoneUpdater.java:230)

        at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.main(TimezoneUpdater.java:634
)
Caused by: tools.tzdb.DateTimeException: Invalid value for SecondOfDay value: 90000
        at tools.tzdb.ChronoField.checkValidValue(ChronoField.java:173)
        at tools.tzdb.LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(LocalTime.java:210)
        at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.parseMonthDayTime(TzdbZoneRulesCompi
ler.java:475)
        at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.parseRuleLine(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.
java:399)
        at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.parseFile(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:354)
        ... 5 more
```

This issue is the same as the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52931705/error-updating-tzdata-2018f-released-2018-10-18-with-tzupdater-2-2-0), that was occurring with the 2018f version. The 2018g release should fix this bug, as explained [here](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2018-October/000052.html) . So, why do we still have this problem ?

Here are the command we used :

```
c:\data\java>java -jar tzupdater.jar -V
tzupdater version 2.2.0-b01
JRE tzdata version: tzdata2018e
tzupdater tool would update with tzdata version: tzdata2018g

c:\data\java>java -version
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

Could someone tell us what we are doing wrong? Many thanks in advance !

Comment: It seems that to make use of the new rearguard-versions, you need to create them using the `make tarballs` command. (I found this mentioned in the [announcement for 2018e](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2018-May/000050.html) )

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment Hulk. And sorry for this duplicate Matt, my reasearch gave no results.