# How can I update Java timezone database to the last version?

Tags: java, java-8, timezone

It looks like TZUpdater is broken.  I get this error when running it:

```
# /usr/local/java/bin/java -jar tzupdater.jar -l
Using https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzdata-latest.tar.gz as source for tzdata bundle.
Failed: java.lang.Exception: Failed while parsing file '/tmp/tz.tmp_5/asia' on line 1655 'Rule  Japan   1948    1951    -   Sep Sat>=8  25:00   0   S'
java.lang.Exception: Failed while parsing file '/tmp/tz.tmp_5/asia' on line 1655 'Rule  Japan   1948    1951    -   Sep Sat>=8  25:00   0S'
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.parseFile(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:377)
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.compile(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:191)
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.<init>(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:307)
    at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.ExternalModule.compileToJSRBinary(ExternalModule.java:153)
    at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.run(TimezoneUpdater.java:230)
    at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.main(TimezoneUpdater.java:634)
Caused by: tools.tzdb.DateTimeException: Invalid value for SecondOfDay value: 90000
    at tools.tzdb.ChronoField.checkValidValue(ChronoField.java:173)
    at tools.tzdb.LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(LocalTime.java:210)
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.parseMonthDayTime(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:475)
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.parseRuleLine(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:399)
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.parseFile(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:354)
    ... 5 more
```

I am using Java version 1.8.0_191 and TZUpdater version 2.2.0

Comment: Hi, this can help, quite similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/52933738/1004631 and https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8212684 for reference

Comment: Thanks a lot, since I need the last version of the timezones (2018g) it worked using this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52931705/error-updating-tzdata-2018f-released-2018-10-18-with-tzupdater-2-2-0/53442095#53442095