# Java TZUpdater fails to compile TZDB version 2019a because of parsing error in /tmp/tz.tmp/asia

Tags: java, timezone

I use AWS Elastic Beanstalk and every year the playtform version gets updated with the latest timezones. This year I noticed that some countries did not update daylight saving time so I decided to update it manually.

The problem is that with the latest TZDB version, I get a compilation error:

```
$ java -jar tzupdater.jar -v -l https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzdata-latest.tar.gz
Using https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzdata-latest.tar.gz as source for tzdata bundle.
java.home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-0.43.amzn1.x86_64/jre
java.vendor: Oracle Corporation
java.version: 1.8.0_201
tzupdater version 2.2.0-b01
JRE tzdata version: tzdata2018c
Downloaded file to /tmp/tz.tmp/tzdata.tar.gz
tzupdater tool would update with tzdata version: tzdata2019a
Compiling TZDB version 2019a
Parsing file: /tmp/tz.tmp/africa
Parsing file: /tmp/tz.tmp/antarctica
Parsing file: /tmp/tz.tmp/asia
Failed: java.lang.Exception: Failed while parsing file '/tmp/tz.tmp/asia' on line 1860 'Rule    Japan   1948    1951    -   Sep Sat>=8  25:00   0   S'
java.lang.Exception: Failed while parsing file '/tmp/tz.tmp/asia' on line 1860 'Rule    Japan   1948    1951    -   Sep Sat>=8  25:00   0   S'
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.parseFile(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:377)
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.compile(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:191)
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.<init>(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:307)
    at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.ExternalModule.compileToJSRBinary(ExternalModule.java:153)
    at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.run(TimezoneUpdater.java:230)
    at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.main(TimezoneUpdater.java:634)
Caused by: tools.tzdb.DateTimeException: Invalid value for SecondOfDay value: 90000
    at tools.tzdb.ChronoField.checkValidValue(ChronoField.java:173)
    at tools.tzdb.LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(LocalTime.java:210)
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.parseMonthDayTime(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:475)
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.parseRuleLine(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:399)
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.parseFile(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:354)
    ... 5 more
```

How does anybody update to the latest version if it does not compile?

Comment: A new era name has been declared in Japan only a few days ago. It could be that the latest file is affected by this change, though it shouldn't really affect daylight savings.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52931705/error-updating-tzdata-2018f-released-2018-10-18-with-tzupdater-2-2-0

Comment: I found that @Marvin, thanks. But it is related to the 2018f version. Also the solution there is to use 2018e version which is outdated

Comment: That's why I didn't flag it as "possible duplicate" ;) But seeing that the issue has been open for quite a while now gives little hope for a solution.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the issue with the 2018f and 2019a versions is the same. If anyone thinks that a different solution for the 2019a version might exist that would not work for 2018f, please ping me here, and I will be happy to reopen this question.